# Open Source Task Portal?

Tags: open-source, resource-management

I apologize in advance if this is not an SF question, but I'm thinking it's in the gray.

Are there any good Open Source or atleast fair priced "intranet" project portals where you can have a dashboard, view your tasks as well as your employee's and co-workers tasks so you can see what your team(s) are working on.

I'm looking for something that is not cumbersome to manage, has a clean UI/Dashboard, etc. etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ticket+system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using [Taskfreak](http://www.taskfreak.com/) at my workplace and it's been great for simple project tracking, and filing bugs. It's easy and unencumbered enough that the traders (read: guys who hate technological solutions) here feel comfortable using it.

Answer (score 3):

There are various free products. [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) and [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/) are reasonable. You might like to look at [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/) and [Request Tracker](http://bestpractical.com/rt/) too, although the former is heavily geared towards development and the latter is heavily geared towards cusomter service.

If you're willing to pay money, then [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) is 10USD/year for 10 or fewer users. [Basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/) is 25USD/m.

I can not recommend JIRA enough, but it is costly if you have more than 10 users.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

- [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) Redmine is a flexible project management web application.
- [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) Trac is an enhanced wiki and issue tracking system for software development projects.

We use Redmine.

Comment: I really like redmine for a software development solution over Trac. We currently use Trac for that type of stuff.

But what I am looking for is more of a "Task" management rather than a Project management tool. Where I think Redmine/Trac are PM not Task focused.

I want something where I can login, see my employees task and even add a "Install Quickbooks on so and so's computer" Task to my helpdesk guy. etc. etc. I guess similar to Track-it.

Comment: Redmine is very well suited for that purpose. Just assign an issue to one of your employees. Make sure he/she update the status after task completion.

Answer (score 1):

DotNetNuke is an awesome and highly configurable project that can be used as an Intranet portal.

Comment: Isn't DotNetNuke a CMS, rather than an issue tracker?

Comment: Yes it is.  However, I've used it very successfully in a multitude of roles.  It is very easy to configure and there are tons of modules out there (free and pay) to make it do exactly what you want.  Just because it is a CMS, doesn't mean you have to use it that way.

Answer (score 0):

We use(d) a [twiki](http://twiki.org) for that.

Unfortunately it is hard (meaing: I failed) to make team and management see the benefit of documenting project/task progress in a systematic (read: automatic evaluation / summation is possible) way as opposed to a "pragmatic" (read: outlook, free form (winowrd) reports) approach.

A major factor is the lack of a (working) wysiwyg editor for twiki.

Answer (score 0):

We've used Dotproject before but it feels antiquated. I've been looking at [TeamBox](http://www.teambox.com/) with great interest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that's more geared towards ticketing, I've been using [MySQL's Eventum](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Eventum) for a few years now, and it works wonderfully. I don't know if they have an online demo, but feel free to send me mail and I'll give you an account on my installation to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned elsewhere, http://www.clockingit.com/ can be used as a hosted service or you can download the code and run it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Open Source, but Windows SharePoint Services will cost you nothing, will do all you need, and will integrate quite cleanly with your Active Directory if you have one.

Comment: I thought you had to purchase Sharepoint?

Comment: MOSS yes, WSS no.  "Windows SharePoint Services is provided as part of the Windows Server 2003 operating system and Windows licensing terms apply to its use. Please review the Windows SharePoint Services supplemental licensing information. There is no additional charge for Windows SharePoint Services." (from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/sharepoint/bb400747.aspx).